# Problema con el emulador de android studio, AYUDAA

Tags: android

tengo un pequeño problema con Android Studio y es el siguiente, a la hora de que voy a ver lo que llevo en el proyecto con el emulador este solo me muestra en una esquina toda la pantalla algo reducido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les agradecería su ayuda, muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola user84165, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**,saludos!

Comment: Pudiste solucionarlo? Tengo el mismo problema

Answer (score -1):

**Esto es un problema con el emulador y no de tu código o el layout**, en realidad lo que deberí mostrarse dentro del emulador es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

te sugiero crear otro [AVD](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html) ve a:

**Tools** > **AVD Manager**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: **CP Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.